# How to use memset_s in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, c11

```
android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"
        stl = "stlport_static"
        CFlags.add("-std=iso9899:2011") // I have also used "-std=c11"
        ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
    }
```

I still cannot see memset_s in jni C code. It says undefined reference.

In my c code i have also included string.h, stdlib.h, and stdio.h and also

```
#define STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1 1
```

Still cannot get rid of the error undefined reference error.

If i add the flag Allow_Undefined_symbols it compiles but when ever i call the function memset_s it crashes.

The questions i would like to ask are as follows :

1) In which of the Android NDK tool chains can we get the C11 memset_s api?

2) The other question i have is how can we change the default tool chain for android in the latest android studio with experimental gradle alpha5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find any tool chain that supports C11 for NDK. So i have used a compliant solution for c99 from the following link:

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC06-C.+Beware+of+compiler+optimizations

Which you can customize for your own purpose. I am adding this solution for any one in need.

Answer (score 2):

This functionally of "Annex K" in the C11 standard is optional. It is not implemented in many C libraries.

You can test for conformance to Annex K by means of the macro `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Jens as i have mentioned in the question i have already tried the macro and i do know that it is a part of C11 that is the reason i have already added the tag. May be I have asked in a wrong way let me rephrase it. In which of the Android NDK tool chains can we get the C11 memset_s api? The other question i have is how can we change the default tool chain for android in the latest android studio with experimental grable alpha5?

Comment: It would surprise me if there'd be one. I haven't heard of a C library implementation in the Linux world that does implement Annex K, nor of one that has plans for it.